# bundle throwing error Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: with Mavericks and ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, gcc, osx-mavericks

Getting the below error when i run `bundle` from a 1.8.7 app. I just upgraded to Mavericks and am using rbenv.

Things I've tried already:

1) uninstall and reinstall rbenv and ruby-build

2) dropped the directory and re-cloned

3) installing x-code cli with `xcode-select --install`

4) brew install apple-gcc42

5) deleting the root ruby file (2.0) and replacing with 1.8

6) brew unlink apple-gcc42

None of the above have worked yet.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for re.h... no
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling parser.c
parser.rl:165:20: error: expected '(' after 'if'
            if RTEST(rb_funcall(klass, i_json_creatable_p, 0)) {
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:445:18: note: expanded from macro 'RTEST'
#define RTEST(v) !(((VALUE)(v) & ~Qnil) == 0)
             ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [parser.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/ryan/C2/c2/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.4.6 for   inspection.
Results logged to /Users/ryan/C2/c2/vendor/bundle/gems/json-1.4.6/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.4.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.4.6'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 2):

I just got something similar when I changed an old Ruby 1.9.3 project to Ruby 2.2.0 and tried to `bundle`.

I got errors like `parser.rl:139:20: error: expected '(' after 'if'" and "` and `accept.c:128:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'TRAP_BEG'`.

**The fix was to upgrade the gems that failed to build**: `bundle update json kgio` in my case, where the `json` gem and then the `kgio` gem failed to build.

If you've locked down the versions of a problematic gem in your `Gemfile`, you might want to unlock them, too. E.g. change `gem "json", "1.1.6"` to just `gem "json"`. Though you should of course make sure you know *why* it was locked down in the first place.

When you just do `bundle`, it tries to install/build the gem versions listed in `Gemfile.lock`. Those will be the versions you installed previously on Ruby 1.8.7 in your case, or 1.9.3 in my case. I guess those gem versions are old enough that they simply don't compile for a newer Ruby.

Comment: I just had this problem upgrading rubies to v2.0 with the json gem.  @Henrik N's solution worked for me.  I had originally tried just `bundle update` to attempt to update all the gems, but that failed with an error.  Running bundle update just for `json` did the trick.